# NFC Checking the MessageReceived handler early

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, nfc

(Windows Phone 8 NFC) When detecting a nearby device, is it possible to execute the MessageReceivedHandler in the DeviceArrived Event? I'm not sure how to get the ProximityMessage from the ProximityDevice. The purpose is when a device arrives, I need to know immediately whether it has content; in fact, getting the handler to execute first would be optimal, but I doubt that's possible. I thought, alternatively, of a workaround that involved using the Dispatcher, but because the Dispatcher would run later (not UI thread) it didn't help. I'm not a threading expert; maybe someone can enlighten me as to how to break from the thread for an instant, then return. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that'll happen but you can set a bool and a dispatcher timer like...

```
void DeviceArrived
{
DeviceHere = true;
}
```

and

```
void dt_Tick
{
  if (DeviceHere == true)
  {
  //Write your reading code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as desired. When reading from the device, you need a ProximityMessage.